# Output of the ffmpeg -r command

Tags: ffmpeg

when I execute

```
ffmpeg -i >video file> -r 24 -t 100 %d.jpeg
```

I see output lines like

```
frame= 47 ... time=6.70
```

which I guess is the time stamp of frame 47. But this data only shows up for some frames, can I get it to come for all frames?

Comment: This is just debugging data. If you want the timestamp associated with each output frame, use the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/841872/how-do-i-extract-the-timestamps-associated-with-frames-ffmpeg-extracts-from-a-vi/842397#842397 -- seeing that you are the OP of that question, I assume it works for you. Use the `showinfo` filter to get the output you want. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289181/getting-log-line-for-each-extracted-frame-from-ffmpeg

Comment: problem is that worked on an old ubuntu box on which I didn't make note of the ffmpeg version. Running your answer to my old question on a fresh box throws some errors

Comment: `Unrecognized option 'filter:v'
Failed to set value 'fps=fps=25, showinfo' for option 'filter:v'`

Comment: You are running an outdated version on that fresh box, probably due to installing it with `apt-get` or `yum`, which often gives you old versions. Try compiling ffmpeg yourself, or [downloading a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: That worked :), if I could send you a beer I would :)